# installing PAR::Packer Module on Perl 5.16

Tags: linux, perl

I was trying to install a module named "PAR::Packer" on active Perl version 5.16 running on  64 bit Ubuntu machine . But the installation was exiting with some errors :

```
      this is the error :
      -----------------
      main.o: In function `main':
      main.c:(.text.startup+0x35): undefined reference to `pthread_atfork'
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
      make[1]: *** [par] Error 1
      make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/.cpan/build/PAR-Packer-1.017-dIGsgr/myldr'
      make: *** [subdirs] Error 2
      RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.017.tar.gz
      /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
     'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
      Running make test
      Can't test without successful make
      Running make install
      Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
      Failed during this command:
      RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.017.tar.gz              : make NO
      ----------------
```

I also tried with PPM to install this module .  PPM installation was successful , but I was not able to run the "pp" command .

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: The location that it installed pp may not be in your path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . But still am not able install PAR::Packer module

Answer (score 0):

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=629670

seems to be a bug in debian 64 bit. Changed where they locate the libs.